# Input variables to an array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a fiddle here with how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/EtFVN/3/

I succeed to get all the variables into an array so it alerts in the end. But I'm missing the variable "AltType" that appears if you click on any of the list-items.

The thing is that you should be able to select an item, and then get it into the array in company with it's own "group".

Here is how it's created:

```
    var ChooseAltType = $("<div>").appendTo(field_firstchild);

    $('<div id="chooseCustomFields'
    + field_id
    + '" class="wrapper-customfields" tabindex="1"><span>Choose Type</span>'
    + '<ul id="chooseCustomField'
    + field_id
    + '" class="dropdown">'
    + '<li class="choose_Checkbox"><i class="fa-icon-check"></i>Checkbox</li>'
    + '<li class="choose_Alternatives"><i class="fa-icon-list-ul"></i> Alternatives</li>'
    + '<li class="choose_Dropdown"><i class="fa-icon-list-alt"></i> Dropdown</li>'
    + '<li class="choose_TextField"><i class="fa-icon-font"></i> Text</li>'
    + '</ul></div>').appendTo(field_secondchild).addClass("metro three-d")
    .on('click', 'li', function() {
        AltType = $(this).attr('class');
        var clean =  AltType;
        var AltType = clean.substring(clean.indexOf('_') +1);
        alert(AltType)      
    });
```

Comment: Can you work on reducing your code to a bare minimum example?

Comment: I reduced it plenty! But I can try a bit more :)

Comment: @j08691 Okey, I've reduced it a bit more, hope its enough! New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EtFVN/3/

Comment: @Kim If you have a JS question, it would be nice to post the generated HTML markup and script, but not the original PHP (or ASP) code.

Comment: @feeela Allright, thing is that everything is dynamically created, but I will make an updated version